# How do I add Time Frame functionality

Tags: pine-script-v5

I am trying to create an alert when ever a support is broken for partciular time frame. Currently i have no option to select time frame and if i incorporate timeframe argument in indictaor, script simply doesn't compile and return the error. So how can I add time frame option to this function.

```
f_crossed_under() =>
    ret = false
    for x = 0 to array.size(sr_up_level) > 0 ? array.size(sr_up_level) - 1 : na by 1
        float mid = math.round_to_mintick((array.get(sr_up_level, x) + array.get(sr_dn_level, x)) / 2)
        if close[1] >= mid and close < mid
            ret := true
            ret
            
    ret
```

I am trying to add timeframe functioality to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to the function the serie value of close in your chosen timeframe :

```
// For the timeframe 'One Day' 
close_in_my_timeframe = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", close)

f_crossed_under(serie_of_close) =>
    ret = false
    for x = 0 to array.size(sr_up_level) > 0 ? array.size(sr_up_level) - 1 : na by 1
        float mid = math.round_to_mintick((array.get(sr_up_level, x) + array.get(sr_dn_level, x)) / 2)
        if serie_of_close[1] >= mid and serie_of_close < mid
            ret := true
            ret
    ret

// Then you can you for example :
my_state_for_alert = f_crossed_under(close_in_my_timeframe)
```

Comment: Pardon my code understanding level but I have a question. close_in_my_timeframe has not been called in function f_crossed_under anywhere in your responce? Would your code work?

Comment: @Mani I complete my answer with an example. Hope it helps